# How to hide appened li element without id or class

Tags: jquery

How to hide appended `li` element without id or class

This is my code.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="blog-node-form">
<ul class="vertical-tabs-list">`enter code here`
    <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>Menu settings</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>URL path settings</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>Revision information</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>Authoring information</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><strong>Publishing options</strong></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>

    jQuery("#blog-node-form").on('each','ul.vertical-tabs-list li',function(){
        if(jQuery(this).find('strong:contains("Menu settings")').length>0 || jQuery(this).find('strong:contains("Authoring information")').length>0)
       {
         jQuery("#edit-menu").hide();
         jQuery(this).hide();
       }
    });
```

Here I'm trying to hide specific `li`.

The `ul` is appended in my page using ajax.

Comment: Show your html code a well.

Comment: Can you add this in plunker?

Comment: What is `.on('each',`?

Comment: @Satpal I think it's an attempt to delegate looking for those elements in the future

Comment: <form action="" method="post" id="blog-node-form">
<ul class="vertical-tabs-list">
 <li>
  <a href="#"><strong>Menu settings</strong></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#"><strong>URL path settings</strong></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#"><strong>Revision information</strong></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#"><strong>Authoring information</strong></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#"><strong>Publishing options</strong></a>
 </li>
</ul>
</form>

Comment: Rather than dump unformatted code blobs into comment blocks, always update the actual question with formatted code and additional relevant details

Comment: this ul is appended in to form

Comment: You need [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and a decent read [DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

Comment: I have posted an answer for this question please check answer of Mr. HK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), Here in snippet I have used `setTimeout` to simulate appending of `ul` dynamically using `$.ajax()` operation.

```js
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;
var list = document.querySelector('#blog-node-form');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      jQuery("#blog-node-form ul.vertical-tabs-list li").find('strong:contains("Menu settings")').parent().parent().hide();
      jQuery("#blog-node-form ul.vertical-tabs-list li").find('strong:contains("Authoring information")').parent().parent().hide();
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(list, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  var data = '<ul class="vertical-tabs-list"> \
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Menu settings</strong></a> </li>\
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>URL path settings</strong></a> </li> \
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Revision information</strong></a> </li> \
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Authoring information</strong></a> </li> \
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Publishing options</strong></a> </li> \
    </ul> ';
  jQuery("#blog-node-form").append(data)
}, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="blog-node-form">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).each(function(index,element))
```

Get the number of **li**s, use *index* to find it.
Just for an example:

```
if(index===5)
    element.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.
You just don't need to each loop.

**Code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" id="blog-node-form">
    <ul class="vertical-tabs-list"> 
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Menu settings</strong></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>URL path settings</strong></a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Revision information</strong></a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Authoring information</strong></a> </li> 
        <li> <a href="#"><strong>Publishing options</strong></a> </li> 
    </ul> 
</form>

<script>
    jQuery("#blog-node-form ul.vertical-tabs-list li").find('strong:contains("Menu settings")').parent().parent().hide();
    jQuery("#blog-node-form ul.vertical-tabs-list li").find('strong:contains("Authoring information")').parent().parent().hide();
</script>
```